# 3-level logistic regression

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to analyze a longitudinal data with binary response using 3-level logistic regression. Hierarchical structure of my data looks like this example- students (level 1) are nested within a class(level 2) and the classes are nested within a school (level 3).

Can anyone suggest me some appropriate readings on the `SAS` or `R` codes for performing 3-level mixed effects logistic regression? I am not requesting helps regarding the theory behind 3-level logistic regression. Any examples with `SAS` or `R` codes would be of great help.

Comment: Since your question is as you point out yourself solely about getting your analysis to run in a software, this question would be more appropriate for Stack Overflow. If this is the case, flag it and it will be migrated over there (but don't cross-post).

Comment: Without knowing much about the regression you're trying to perform, and also lacking any information about your familiarity with `R`, this looks like it might be useful?: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Bliese_Multilevel.pdf

Comment: The situation you describe is clearly multilevel, but I don't follow how it's longitudinal. That said, the references [here](http://glmm.wikidot.com/) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I am sorry if I was unclear but the situation I described is not the data I am analyzing. It was just an example. My data has more than 10K subjects in total. There are about 190 clusters with 40-60 subjects in each cluster. Each subject were remeasured about 4-7 times.

Comment: I'm not sure if examples and codes for 3-level multilevel logistic regression analysis are commonly available in books/articles. I thought it could be done in `SAS` with `PROC NLMIXED` or `PROC GLIMMIX` or in `R` with `lme4` package but I were looking for code examples here.

Answer (score 2):

In R you can use the `glmer()` function from the ***[lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf)*** package for mixed effects models.  You specify the effects in the `formula=` option.  For nested random effects you *probably* want something like:

```
model <- glmer(formula = response ~ (1|student|class/block), family=binomial)
```

There are some examples of multi-level models on [R-sessions](http://www.rensenieuwenhuis.nl/r-sessions-16-multilevel-model-specification-lme4/)

and you can fit non-linear responses, such as binomial, with `family=binomial`.